# ANTLR4 using HIDDEN channel causes errors while using skip does not

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlr4

In my grammar I use:

```
WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

when I change this to use HIDDEN channel:

```
WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

I receive errors (extraneous input ' '...) I did not receive while using 'skip'.
I thought, that skipping and sending to a channel does not differ if it comes to a content passed to a parser.

Below you can find a code excerpt in which the parser is executed:

```
    CharStream charStream = new ANTLRInputStream(formulaString);
    FormulaLexer lexer = new FormulaLexer(charStream);
    BufferedTokenStream tokens = new BufferedTokenStream(lexer);
    FormulaParser parser = new FormulaParser(tokens);
    ParseTree tree = parser.startRule();

    StartRuleVisitor startRuleVisitor = new StartRuleVisitor();
    startRuleVisitor.visit(tree);

    VariableVisitor variableVisitor = new VariableVisitor(tokens);
    variableVisitor.visit(tree);
```

And a grammar itself:

```
grammar Formula;


startRule
   : variable RELATION_OPERATOR integer
   ;

integer
   : DIGIT+
   ;

identifier
   : (LETTER | DIGIT) ( DIGIT | LETTER | '_' | '.')+
   ;

tableId
   : 'T_' (identifier | WILDCARD)
   ;

rowId
   : 'R_' (identifier | WILDCARD)
   ;

columnId
   : 'C_' (identifier | WILDCARD)
   ;

sheetId
   : 'S_' (identifier | WILDCARD)
   ;

variable
   : L_CURLY_BRACKET cellIdComponent (COMMA cellIdComponent)+ R_CURLY_BRACKET
   ;

cellIdComponent
   : tableId | rowId | columnId | sheetId
   ;

COMMA
   : ','
   ;

RELATION_OPERATOR
   : EQ
   ;

WILDCARD
   : 'NNN'
   ;

L_CURLY_BRACKET
   : '{'
   ;

R_CURLY_BRACKET
   : '}'
   ;


LETTER
   : ('a' .. 'z') | ('A' .. 'Z')
   ;

DIGIT
   : ('0' .. '9')
   ;


EQ
   : '='
   | 'EQ' | 'eq'
   ;


WS
   : [ \t\r\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN)
   ;
```

String I try to parse:

```
{T_C 00.01, R_010,   C_010} = 1
```

Output I get with channel(HIDDEN) used:

```
line 1:4 extraneous input ' ' expecting {'_', '.', LETTER, DIGIT}
line 1:11 extraneous input ' ' expecting {'T_', 'R_', 'C_', 'S_'}
line 1:18 extraneous input '   ' expecting {'T_', 'R_', 'C_', 'S_'}
line 1:27 extraneous input ' ' expecting RELATION_OPERATOR
line 1:29 extraneous input ' ' expecting DIGIT
```

But if I change channel(HIDDEN) to 'skip' there are no errors.

What is more, I have observed that for more complex grammar than this i get 'no viable alternative at input...' if I use channel(HIDDEN) and once again the error disappear for the 'skip'.

Do you know what may be the cause of it?

Comment: Please post the code that executes the parser, the problem may be in there.

Comment: Added. If it is not sufficient please let me know :)

Comment: Well, that code looks correct... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ are you using an up to date version of ANTLR?

Comment: Can you upload a grammar file and text to be parsed?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I am using the most recent antlr4 4.6 version.

Comment: @KvanTTT added ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `CommonTokenStream` instead of `BufferedTokenStream`. See `BufferedTokenStream` [description on github](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/4.6/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/BufferedTokenStream.java#L22):

> This token stream ignores the value of {@link Token#getChannel}. If your
>   parser requires the token stream filter tokens to only those on a particular
>   channel, such as {@link Token#DEFAULT_CHANNEL} or
>   {@link Token#HIDDEN_CHANNEL}, use a filtering token stream such a
>   {@link CommonTokenStream}.